# How can I find media files not encoded with a specific codec?

Tags: video, find, codecs

I would like to standardize my video collection on a specific video codec (for instance the x265 High Efficiency Video Codec). I know I can obtain the codec in use from a single file using for instance 'mediainfo filename | grep "Codec ID"' Which will output the video codec followed by the audio codec for each file like:

```
Codec ID                                 : V_VP8
Codec ID                                 : A_VORBIS
```

I've reviewed `man find` but I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a sorted list of your codec specific media files under the working directory by

$ mediainfo * | grep -v codec_id | grep .file_extension | cut -f2 -d: > list.txt

where *codec_id* is the codec in question (ex. h264) and *file_extension* is the extension of the container in question (ex. .mkv)

but if the file names have blank spaces between names then the command will not work as desired.

Answer (score 6):

A combination of [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html), [`ffprobe`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html), [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) utilities could be used to print info about all `*.avi`, `*.mp4` files (in the current directory tree recursively) that are NOT encoded using `"h264"` video codec:

```
$ find -name \*.avi -o -name \*.mp4 \
    -exec ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -show_format -of json {} \; |
  jq -c '.format.filename as $path |
         .streams[]? |
         select(.codec_type=="video" and .codec_name!="h264") |
         {codec: .codec_name, path: $path}'
```

To install the utilities, run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg jq findutils
```

The example works on `jq` `1.4`. If `apt-get` version provides an older version; you could [download a newer `jq` binary (just put the downloaded file somewhere in `$PATH`, rename it to `jq` and make it executable: `chmod +x jq`)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/).

Comment: for some reason I get no output whatsoever after changing -name parameter to those I actually have (*.mkv) although there are many files that are not h264. However if I change "h264" to "hevc" I find 2 h264 files.

Comment: @ElderGeek: 1- I've suppressed "jq: error: Cannot iterate over null" message (it means `ffprobe` has not found any streams in the input file). 2- this command prints only those video files that are NOT encoded using h264 (`!=`).¶ There are three parts: find, ffprobe, and jq: I recommend to debug them separately i.e., first make sure that `find` finds the necessary files then ensure that `ffprobe` can extract the code info from a given video file then use `jq` to filter the `ffprobe` output.

Comment: both find and ffprobe appear to work as advertised.

Comment: @ElderGeek: save the ffprobe's output in a file `input.json`, feed it to your `jq`  command, save it to the `output.json` file then if `output.json` is not what you want then provide the desired output and post all that info (input.json, output.json, desired_output.json, the complete `jq` command that you use as a separate question).

Comment: for some reason I couldn't get the -or switch to work in this context I did get reasonable output using `find -name \*.mkv -exec ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -show_format -of json {} \; |       jq -c '.format.filename as $path |
             .streams[] |
             select(.codec_type=="video" and .codec_name!="hevc") |
             {codec: .codec_name, path: $path}'`

Comment: @ElderGeek: assume that I test my answer (unless stated otherwise) and therefore if something doesn't work then you should provide additional information (steps to reproduce, what do you expect to happen exactly, what happens instead, what software versions do you use and any other information that you consider relevant) e.g., `.streams[]?` does work on my machine (`jq --version`: `jq-1.4-1-e73951f`). Obviously, `-or` works on Ubuntu (though it is not POSIX compliant), use `-o` if it is an issue. If you can't make `find` command with `-o` to work then ask the question specifically about `find`

Comment: Adding the ? fails on jq version 1.3 (current in the repositories for 14.04) as of writing.

Comment: no problem with -o problem was with -or

Comment: @ElderGeek: you could download a newer jq version (it is a single file). I've updated the answer to mention the required minimal jq version explicitly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40787/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-j-f-sebastian).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this small python script together with find to print all files with specific codec:

**filterByCodec.py**

```py
import os
import sys
import json

inputPath = sys.argv[1]
codec = sys.argv[2]
type = sys.argv[3]

cmd = 'ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -print_format json ' + inputPath
output = os.popen(cmd).read()
output = json.loads(output)

if not 'streams' in output:
    sys.exit(0)
for stream in output['streams']:
    if stream['codec_name'] == codec and stream['codec_type'] == type:
        print inputPath
        sys.exit(0)
```

This will call `ffprobe`, store its output in json string, iterate over all streams and print the input path in case codec name and type match. You will need `ffprobe` for this. You can get it as a static build from [here](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) if you don't have it installed on your system.

Then you can call it on every file using `find` like this:

```
find . -type f -exec python filterByCodec.py {} hevc video \;
```

this will print all videos containing HEVC video codec. More examples:

```
find . -type f -exec python filterByCodec.py {} h264 video \;
find . -type f -exec python filterByCodec.py {} mp3 audio \;
```

You can extend the script and move those files into some directory or whatever. This could look something like this:

```py
cmd = 'mv ' + inputPath + ' onlyhevcDir'
os.system(cmd)
```

I know that this is not the best way to do it, but using python it's pretty simple to do.

Comment: Where does python expect to find the script? I get `python: can't open file 'filterByCodec.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @ElderGeek in the same directory where you run find. But you can copy it either in /usr/local/bin or export path to enable access to it from everywhere

Comment: Thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915661/python-cant-open-file-django-admin-py-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory explains it.

Comment: I got it working by specifying the full path to the script. for some reason just having it on the path or in /usr/local/bin didn't work for me.

Comment: @ElderGeek I'm sorry my previous comment is complete bullshit, putting it to your path can not tell python where to find the script (since its not a executable what we are searching for, its just a script), so providing the full absolute path to script like you did is the best way to do it I guess.

Comment: But we could use [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in front of the script to make it executable without `python <script>` and then putting it in /usr/local/bin would make sense ))

Comment: that works. 2>/dev/null at the end of the command line cleans up the output.

Answer (score 0):

fix issue with spaces by replacing

```
cmd = 'ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -print_format json ' + inputPath
```

with

```
cmd = 'ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -print_format json ' + "\"" + inputPath + "\""
```