# How can I structure jq filters to return video and audio codec information from ffprobe?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, json

In the interest of standardizing my video library I'm trying to find a way to quickly create a list of files that need to be converted. After looking at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781408/how-can-i-find-media-files-not-encoded-with-a-specific-codec) question and its answer (and much googling) I think I have the basics figured out, but I'm having trouble elaborating on the jq section. For reference, the jq command I'm starting with is as follows:

```
jq -c '.format.filename as $path | 
    .streams[]? | 
    select(.codec_type=="video" and .codec_name!="h264") | 
    .codec_name as $vcodec | 
    {video: $vcodec, path: $path}'
```

and, for simplicity's sake, let's say this is what's being fed to jq:

```
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "hevc",
            "codec_type": "video"
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "aac",
            "codec_type": "audio"
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "Video.mkv"
    }
}
```

which produces the following output:

```
{"video":"hevc","path":"./Video.mkv"}
```

This is great, but I want to go one step further - I would also like to include the codec used for any audio streams. So, given the same input, I would like the following output:

```
{"video":"hevc","audio":"aac","path":"./Video.mkv"}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select both audio and  video codec types and exclude `h264` video:

```
$ jq '.format.filename as $path |
    [.streams[]? | select(.codec_type=="audio" 
                          or (.codec_type=="video" 
                              and .codec_name!="h264")) | 
     {(.codec_type): .codec_name, $path}] | 
    group_by(.path) | map(add) | .[]' input.json
$ jq --version      
jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe
```

If a shell command becomes complex and it takes more than a few lines;
I switch to more verbose Python to manage the complexity:

```py
result = dict(path=data['format']['filename'])
for stream in data['streams']:
    if (stream['codec_type'] == 'audio'
        or (stream['codec_type'] == 'video'
            and stream['codec_name'] != 'h264')):
        result[stream['codec_type']] = stream['codec_name'] # last value wins
```

`data` is the input (`data = json.loads(json_text)`) and `result` is the desired output (`print(json.dumps(result))`).

It should be relatively straightforward to adapt the above code for your particular case if you are more familiar with an imperative programming in Python than with a more functional style in `jq`.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I expanded on your answer a bit by changing/adding this bit at the end: `.[]? | select(.video!="h264") | {video: .video, audio: .audio, path: .path}`. For the moment anyway, I'm only interested in the audio codec if the video codec isn't what I want it to be. Looks like it would be worth spending some time learning python.

Comment: One final note - everything worked fine when testing it on jqplay.org, but was returning a syntax error for an unexpected `$` when running the same command on my computer. Turns out I had jq version 1.4 ('current' version on Debian Jessie), upgrading to version 1.5 fixed this issue.

Comment: @Ziggy114: I've updated the answer to exclude h264 videos and show jq version (I use jq package for Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach.

```
$ jq -M '
  def getpath: {path: .format.filename} ;
  def getcodecs: [
        .streams[]?
      | {(.codec_type):.codec_name}
      | if . == {"video":"h264"} then empty else . end
    ] | add
  ;
  getpath + getcodecs
  ' input.json
```

Output

```
{
  "path": "Video.mkv",
  "video": "hevc",
  "audio": "aac"
}
```